# SQL Query | Count with a Condition

Tags: sql, mysql

Requirements:

I need to create a new query. When the Product ID has is empty in my Tickets Table it will show the Serial Number column and count it.

See example below:

Product Table

```
     |--------------------------------------|
     |Product ID | Product Serial NUMBER    |
      --------------------------------------
     |   1       |    SN-0001               |
     ----------------------------------------
     |   2       |    SN-0002               |
     ----------------------------------------
     |   3       |    SN-0003               |
     ----------------------------------------
     |   4       |    SN-0004               |
     ----------------------------------------
```

Tickets Table

```
     |-------------------------------------------------|
     |Ticket ID  |    Product ID  |     Serial Number  |
      -------------------------------------------------|
     |   1       |        2       |                    |
     ---------------------------------------------------
     |   2       |                |     SN-0003        |
     ---------------------------------------------------
     |   3       |                |     SN-0001        |
     --------------------------------------------------
     |   4       |        1       |                    |
     ---------------------------------------------------
     |   5       |        1       |                    |
     ---------------------------------------------------
     |   6       |        2       |                    |
     ---------------------------------------------------
```

Final QUERY Table

```
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------|
     |   ID      |    Product ID              |  Total Serial Number Count  |
      -----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |   1       |         1                  |        3                    |
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |   2       |         2                  |        2                    |
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |   3       |         3                  |        1                    |
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |   4       |         4                  |        0                    |
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Reason:

Currently there was a serial number field and since it was redundant I removed the serial number in my tickets.

CURRENTLY BUILD QUERY

Currently This is my query.

```
SELECT

     "Tickets"."ID" as "ID",
     COUNT("Tickets"."Product ID") over(PARTITION BY "Tickets"."Product ID"  ) as " Total Machine",
     to_string(count("Tickets"."ID")) as "Total Tickets"
     FROM  "Tickets" 
     GROUP BY "Tickets"."ID",
     "Tickets"."Product ID"
```

Hope this is all clear. Thank you

Comment: You want a left join + group by + row numbering . The last one depends on your MySql version. Please tag the question with  a proper version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use left join on Products and Tickets, then coalesce ID's and count:

```
select row_number() over (order by coalesce(p.ProductId, t.ProductId)) RN,
       coalesce(p.ProductId, t.ProductId) ProductId, 
       count(t.ticketId) TotalCount
from Product p 
left join Tickets t on p.SerialNumber = t.SerialNumber or p.ProductId = t.ProductID
group by coalesce(p.ProductId, t.ProductId)
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jn0b-GRJ)